# youtube api video url format

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

In api response we get following attribute to get the video url

```
 <media:content 
        url='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...'
        type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video'
        isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='5'/>
```

is the url format fixed in the api response or is subject to change? Also the the video url contains certain metadata like developers key etc.

I do not want to store parts of URL which do not change between different URLS. For eg. www.youtube.com and the developers key etc.

Can I do this? Can I get URLs in a particular format so that I can parse it while storing and re-construct it while rendering the video?

Please suggest ways to compress or eliminate redundancy in youtube api response video URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to store the minimum amount of information to uniquely identify a video, that would be the video id, which is `yt:videoid` in v2 Data API responses.

Using the video id, you can construct a link to the watch page via http://youtu.be/**VIDEO_ID**, or add an instance of the iframe embedded player to your page using the [`YT.Player` constructor](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)'s `videoId` parameter.